# Can I compare a Cohen's d to a log-response ratio in a meta-analysis?

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size, cohens-d

I'm conducting a meta-analysis and I'm wondering if I can make direct comparisons between different types of effect sizes? For example, can I compare a Cohen's d calculated from one study to a log-response ratio to another? I am wondering if this is an ok practice or not because for some studies it is natural to compute the Cohen's d (or Hedge's g) and others it is more natural to compute the log-response ratio, depending on whether the study reports standard deviations.

Comment: Supposing you did that and calculated an overall summary effect size. Would that be a log-response ratio or Hedges' g?

Comment: Right, so this would be an apples to oranges comparison?